# mysql delete datetime entries outside of full hour

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table where I get entries every 15 minutes date_time (datetime) like the following example:

```
2022-02-01 00:00:00
2022-02-01 00:15:00
2022-02-01 00:30:00
2022-02-01 00:45:00
2022-02-01 01:00:00
2022-02-01 01:15:00
2022-02-01 01:30:00
2022-02-01 01:45:00
2022-02-01 02:00:00
2022-02-01 02:15:00
2022-02-01 02:30:00
2022-02-01 02:45:00
```

And I want to delete every entry beside the "full hour" entry -> so result should be:

```
2022-02-01 00:00:00
2022-02-01 01:00:00
2022-02-01 02:00:00
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much

I tried already the manual selection like "all entries with 00:15:00" -> but I would like to create it in one query

Comment: What about `DELETE * FROM your_table WHERE MINUTE(date_column) > 0`?

Comment: Also consider you should improve your question by posting table definition...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use

```
DELETE  
FROM your_table 
WHERE MINUTE(date_column) > 0
```